# JqueryMobile loading external script in body does not solve my ajax navigation issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I see some others (e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501079/jquery-mobile-how-to-call-the-external-java-script-function-from-html)) have had trouble using external javascript scripts in JQuery Mobile - as of today I have joined their ranks.

I have a single external js script (controllers.js) which contains code that affects several pages on the site. It is loaded on every page of the site. I put the js file just before the  tag it works fine on the initial page load. However when I navigate thereafter (using the JQM Ajax methods) all functions in the script stop working. I would have thought the script would remain in cache - but heyho. Anyhow there's an [FAQ](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html) which answers this question and I've implemented their suggestion which is: "...to reference the same set of stylesheets and scripts in the head of every page." I have done this but when I do even on the first page load the js doesn't fire. There aren't page specific scripts - so the remainder of that FAQ does not apply.

My cut down html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/static/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/static/jquery-mobile/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">

        <script src="/static/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/static/jquery-mobile/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

      <!-- CSS: implied media="all" -->
    </head>


    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id = "main-page">

            <div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;">
            </div>

            <div id = "home" data-role="content">
                <input type ='button' id = "some_btn" value="press me">
            </div>

        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/controllers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and within the javascript file

```
controllers.js

$('#some_btn').click(function()
{
    alert('button pressed');
});
```

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the content in the `#page` is loaded dynamically via ajax, click will not work, since it only works on elements that are on the page when the script is called.

You need to use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$('body').on('click','#some_btn',function()
{
    alert('button pressed');
});
```

Comment: Hi @fatman. Thanks for your input here - this is driving me a little doolally. Would the same be true for select change events? i.e. I presume I'd need to do something like $('body').on('change','#some_select',function(){}) ?

Comment: Hi, the method described by fatman is also known as 'Just-In-Time' initialization, which mean we are binding events before the DOM is ready. To your question, yes you can do the same with any elemnt expected to be in the dom. You could also bind to the document. $(document).on(event-name, element-id, function() {})